# No matching function call

Tags: c++

```
In member function ‘void reviewData::showMaxReviews() const’:   
reviewData.cpp:130:46: error: no matching function for call to 
‘avlTree<std::basic_string<char> >::Findmax(std::string&, double&, unsigned int&) const’
 purchase.Findmax( name, points, counter);
reviewData.cpp:130:46: note: candidates are:
In file included from reviewData.h:6:0,
             from reviewData.cpp:5:
avlTree.h:132:7: note: bool avlTree<myType>::Findmax(std::string&, double&, unsigned int&) [with myType = std::basic_string<char>;
std::string = std::basic_string<char>] <near match>
bool avlTree<myType>::Findmax( string & name, double & points, unsigned int & count )

bool avlTree<myType>::Findmax( string &name, double &points, unsigned int &count )

// This is how product is declared in reviewdata.h
avlTree<string> purchase;

void reviewData::showMaxReviews() const
      string name;
        double points = 0;
        unsigned int counter = 0;
        bool cool;
         purchase.Findmax( name, points, counter);
```

I am having trouble figuring out what exactly is the problem here because I think I am passing the right parameters however I am still unable to compile. I suspect it has something to do with passing by reference but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showMaxReviews` function is marked as `const`, which means it can not modify any of the member variables of the `reviewData` class. That means it can not call functions, it `this` or on member objects, that at not `const`.

The `findMaxReview` function is *not* marked as `const`, therefore it can not be called. As you see if you read the error message, the compiler is attempting to call a `const` function.

Comment: @yasky If this solves your problem, then consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Please [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about it if you haven't already (and perhaps read again if you have read it). If the answer doesn't solve your problem, but it is helpful, then consider voting it up.